# WPF - binding get property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrid with form and I would like to notify another get property.
Here is my example:

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> Data
{
   get => _data;
   set {
     _data = value;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
   }
}

public int Summary => Data.Sum(data => data.Number);
```

**XAML**

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    ...
     <TextBox Title="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"/>
    ...
  </DataGrid>

<StackPanel>
  <Label Content="Summary: "/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

When I write number to datagrid, Summary is still 0. 
How to notify Summary property, when I change value in collection?
Thanks

Comment: I use a custom attribute `NotifiesOn` described [here](http://www.codecadwallader.com/2013/04/08/inotifypropertychanged-3-of-3-without-the-reversed-notifications/)

Comment: Thanks, but PropertyChanged is called when is called property setter. But when I have collection of objects and I changed any object, PropertyChanged will not be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang

What you need is a notification whenever any item changes in the Collection.

**Update:**

Say Data that will appear in the Grid is:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private int _Salary;
    public int Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return _Salary;
        }
        set
        {
            _Salary = value;
            SalaryChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public Action SalaryChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of ObservableCollection - use this:

```
public class ObsCollection : ObservableCollection<Data>
{
    private Action SalaryChanged;
    public ObsCollection(Action NotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        SalaryChanged = NotifyPropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Data item)
    {
        item.SalaryChanged = SalaryChanged;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {            
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        SalaryChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();
        SalaryChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Finally - In the View Model

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObsCollection _Data = null;

    public ObsCollection Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _Data;
        }
        set
        {
            _Data = value;
        }
    }

    public int TotalSalary
    {
        get
        {
            return _Data.Sum(d => d.Salary);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _Data = new ObsCollection(NotifyTotalSalaryChanged);
        LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        _Data.Add(new Data { Name = "Test1", Salary = 1000 });
        _Data.Add(new Data { Name = "Test2", Salary = 2000 });
        _Data.Add(new Data { Name = "Test3", Salary = 3000 });
        Notify("Data");
    }

    private void NotifyTotalSalaryChanged()
    {
        Notify("TotalSalary");
    }

    #region Property Changed Stuff
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

=============================================
Xaml is merely:

```
<Window x:Class="CstomObserve.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CstomObserve"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TotalSalary, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you, could you show me how I use it? I use https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged, would it be possible to somehow use it?

Comment: Whenever you add/remove a new Object to the collection. Notify the Summary property there. Check if that works for you.

Comment: I would like to update Summary, also when object property in collection changed, not only add/remove.

Comment: @bluray - Got it working. a little crappy but works :)

Comment: Hope this helps...!! Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is easier to use a `BindingList`. It has an event `ListChanged` that is raised if

- one of its items raise itself a `PropertyChanged` event
- an item was added
- an item was removed
- an item was moved

It will give you information what kind of change was detected (`ListChangedType`) and where in the list the change happend (`NewIndex` and `OldIndex`). This solution implies, that your `Data` class also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

This would imply the following changes in your **viewmodel**

```
// if you do not change the list object, there is no need to raise PropertyChanged in setter
public BindingList<Data> Data { get; set; } = new BindingList<Data>();

// constructor
public ViewModel(){
    // Update property Summary if our list changes.
    List.ListChanged += (sender, arg) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Summary));
}
```